# Trying to create a marker out of an image with rounded corners (Google maps)

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps, canvas

I am trying to create my own marker in google maps for my application. For that I am creating an image with rounded corners (tested it separately and used this example (jsfiddle.net/FLaee/67/) to start off). Beside that I used [this](https://gist.github.com/viktorkelemen/1451945) to implement the the picture into google-maps as an marker-image. My Code is based on the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/).
After combining the two working components I was not able to see any marker on the map.

The point of this post is: I am not able to see the mistake I made

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex icons</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// round image
function createMarker(width, height, radius) {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        roundedImage(0, 0, 100, 100, 55);
        context.clip();
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    };
    img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sky-bg2.jpg";
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function roundedImage(x, y, width, height, radius) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    context.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
    context.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
    context.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
    context.lineTo(x, y + radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
    context.closePath();
}



// The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
// to the base of the flagpole.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: -33.9, lng: 151.2}
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  // Adds markers to the map.

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
  // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
  // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
  var image = {
    //url: 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    url: createMarker(20, 20, 4),
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    //size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    size: new google.maps.Size(100, 100),
        // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    //origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    //anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 20)
  };
  // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
  // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
  // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
      map: map,
      icon: image,
     //icon: createMarker(25, 25, 4),
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}

  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with your code `Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined`

Comment: If I fix that, then I get: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Comment: Thank you. I just did not see the missing parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am sorry for this silly question. After adding "context" as a parameter to roundedImage and knowing the problem is caused by "toDataURL" it was very easy to fix this Problem.
[Why you have to use resources from the same origin.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)